# eclipse how to configure tomcat that install from package manager?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

eclipse configure tomcat install from tar.gz just extract them and put their install direction to configure. Now, I install tomcat by 'dnf' in fedora?it's relevant file is divided to multiple direction. I try put relevant direction  to configure, but no effect.

Comment: What do you mean 'no affect'? Do you get an error? What code have you tried? Please include more ifnormation

Comment: That is a spelling mistake. I mean that i try use those divided direction to as installation direction in eclipse configure window, but the eclipse can't recongnize tomcat i installed by dnf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring a Tomcat server means that Eclipse has to know where the necessary files are to launch that server correctly. As the [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_won.27t_the_New_Server_Runtime_dialog_recognize_my_Linux_installed_version_of_Tomcat.3F) points out, that's not always possible with a distribution's package.

Use the .tar.gz download for your development.