# How to install and configure Tomcat for eclipse IDE in macOS?

Tags: eclipse, macos, tomcat

Yes I know there are various similar questions like.

> [eclipse how to configure tomcat that install from package manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909592/eclipse-how-to-configure-tomcat-that-install-from-package-manager)

but not finding any solution to the problem I am facing.
**What I am trying to do:**

- Install Eclipse on macOS
- Install Tomcat 8/8.5 on same machine
- Configure Tomcat to test Servlet developed in eclipse

**What I have done so far:** 
1. Installed Eclipse
2. Installed tomcat using `brew install tomcat@8` :**nothing else done** 
3. Tried adding Server in Eclipse with path : `/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@8`

Comment: Issue Solved added solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 01 :Download Files Required

First Download the Version you Need for your project.
Make sure you download **Core zip file from the link below:**

- Download Apache 7 Tomcat from [this link](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi).
- Download Apache 8 Tomcat from [this link](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi).
- Download Apache 9 Tomcat from [this link](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi).
- Download Apache 10 (Alpha) Tomcat from [this link](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi).
  [image]

  > Select .Zip from above section
  >   Once you have downloaded it, unzip it to a location

### Step 02 :Setting up Server in Eclipse

- Open Eclipse Environment
- Click on Servers Tab
- Click on No servers are available. Click this link to create a new server...
- Click Tomcat v(your downloaded version) Server **and Next**
- Choose the extracted folder as path and runtime.
- **DONE!**

Comment: Can you Accept your answer?

Comment: @nitind I was unable to accept that day because question was't 2 days old.